# How do I insert an entry to an SQL table using a variable received from POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, post

I am trying to pass text variables from a form form a previous page and insert it into a SQL table. The problem I'm having is on the line: $sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES ($firstName, 'smith')";.

If I were to replace "$firstName" with a basic string like "John", the name and last name would be inserted into the SQL table as intended. But, since I'm trying to insert a text value gathered from a form, I need to be able to use the non-static variables but for some reason that I cannot figure out, doesn't work. From everything I read online, just adding the variable into the parameter should make it work but it just doesn't.

I'm very new to this so I'm sorry if my question is confusing. Also, I am fairly certain that the issue does not lie on the file with the form on it.
Any help would be so awesome. thanks!

Here is the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
<html>
<?php

$username = $_Post['username'];
$email = $_Post['email'];
$phone = $_Post['number'];
$firstName = $_Post['firstName'];
$lastName = $_Post['lastName'];
$address = $_Post['address'];
$password = $_Post['password'];

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','database');
 if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "$conn->connect_error";
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES ($firstName, 'smith')";
        $conn->query($sql);
        
        echo $execval;
        echo "Registration successfully...";
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize all other answers,

First, you should **replace $firstName to '$firstName'** because otherwise the text (e.g. "John") will be placed in your query without quotes, like this: `INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES (John, 'smith')` This results in an error because it thinks John is some sort of variable.

---

Second, **your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection**. This is a very serious vulnerability in your website as attackers can use it to read your entire database, and in this case, even create entries in your database, which can result in attackers being able to completely take over your site by writing files!

More in-depth info here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection

The important thing is that the user can control the $firstName variable that you use in `$sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES ('$firstName', 'smith')";` This way the attacker can change the query at that point. He could for example use the payload `', 'a'); DROP TABLE CUSTOMER;--`  to delete all information in the CUSTOMER table.

There are multiple ways to prevent this, but the easiest is to use prepared statements. It looks something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $param_firstName, $param_lastName);
$param_firstName = $firstName; // New line
$param_lastName = $lastName; // New line
$stmt->execute();
```

This way you make sure MySQL doesn't interpret any user input as SQL code, but only as values.

Again, more in-depth information here:

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: I tried using the prepared statements that you provided but every entry that gets inserted into the table has only null values. Do you know what could be causing that? thanks for the info

Comment: I'm not sure if it's required, but I just changed the code in my answer. Could you try that? If that still doen't work, could you confirm that the $_Post variables are not null?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to type $firstName in the 3rd line of your new code. If not, it passes the value "firstName" to the table. I just tried an echo statement with one of the post variables and nothing its coming up so I guess that means there IS something wrong with the post variables. Feels pretty bad because I've been working on this for hours and I'm just not noticing this. Thanks for helping. I'll update if I fix it or need more help

Comment: I think I know what’s wrong with the post variables. I already noticed you used `$_Post` instead of `$_POST` but I thought it might just be a think about your PHP installation. Now I think that’s the problem. Try changing the post variable to ALL CAPS

Comment: thank you so much. I can't believe i spent hours on this. thanks again!!!!!

Comment: Great! Happy to help. The more you do these kind of things the easier they become, so keep practicing!

Answer (score 0):

If you get user input to insert into a database you should always use "Prepared statements" to prevent "SQL injection" or comparable things.

Check here:

[PHP Prepared Statements - w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

The solution of Aashish gaba should work as well but it's unsecure.

This should work for your code:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['number'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','database');
 if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "$conn->connect_error";
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$fname, $lname);

        // set parameters and execute
        $fname = $firstName;
        $lname = $lastName;
        $stmt->execute();
        
        echo $execval;
        echo "Registration successfully...";
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

A nice to have of a prepared statement is the fact that they are reusable like:

```
// set parameters and execute
$fname = "person1_fname";
$lname = "person1_lname";
$stmt->execute();

$fname = "person2_fname";
$lname = "person2_lname";
$stmt->execute();
```

Also don't forget to use somthing to prevent other injections if you print a value to a user. Like:

```
echo "Registration successfully for" . htmlspecialchars($_Post['username']);
```

In addition save the password as hash (with a secure hashfunction) into the database.

Answer (score -1):

As a quick fix you can update your $sql like this:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (fname, lname) VALUES ('{$firstName}', '{$lastName}')";`

But now your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.
At least you should use mysqli escape function before your $sql statement, like this:

```
$firstName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($firstName);
$lastName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($lastName);
```

But I strongly recommend you considering using more advanced options like [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for the further steps and Production environments.

Answer (score -1):

Remplace `$firstName` to `'$firstName'`.
or use [prepared request](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)